# Mysql Group by clause with where on aggregated result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following suborder table.

```
  mysql> select * from suborder;
+-------------+------------------+
| order_state | booking_group_id |
+-------------+------------------+
| CNF         |                1 |
| CNF         |                1 |
| CNF         |                2 |
| BLK         |                1 |
| CNF         |                2 |
+-------------+------------------+
```

I want to fetch all the booking_group_id for which all the order_state is CNF. So for above data, result should only be value '2' as both the rows have order_state = CNF where for booking_data_id '1', two rows are CNF and one row BLK, so will not be part of output.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use grouping with a `HAVING` clause that uses conditional aggregation:

```
select booking_group_id 
from suborder
group by booking_group_id
having count(case when order_state <> 'CNF' then 1 end) = 0
```

or alternatively you can use `NOT EXITS`:

```
select distinct * 
from suborder AS s1
where order_state = 'CNF' and 
      not exists (select 1 
                  from suborder AS s2
                  where s2.booking_group_id = s1.booking_group_id and
                        s2.order_state <> 'CNF')
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter records which has no record for `order_state != 'CNF'`

```
SELECT DISTINCT booking_group_id FROM suborder 
    WHERE order_state = 'CNF' AND booking_group_id not in 
(SELECT DISTINCT booking_group_id from suborder WHERE order_state != 'CNF' )
```

Sub-query in **WHERE** clause fetch list of all `booking_group_id` which has a record for the condition `order_state != 'CNF'` and after that main query filter all id except those which are present in sub-query.

*Another point to be noted:* The sub-query used here will be executed single time because it's independent from main query.